# Move git remote head to earlier commit

Tags: git, github

Can I move the head of a **remote** repository to an earlier commit **without** creating a revert commit? Meaning that after this operation there will be less commits in the remote.

Just to clarify, this is what I am not interested in:

1. Move the head of a local repository (unless necessary for
   manipulating the remove). This question is about remote.
2. Creating a new commit that reverts previous commits.

Possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
git push origin <sha>:HEAD
```

Will set the remote repository's `HEAD` to point at `<sha>`. In general, `git push` can accept any sort of `source:destination` style refspec, so you can for instance change what arbitrary remote branches refer to as well:

```
git push origin master:deploy
```

This would set the remote `deploy` branch to point at the same commit as the local `master` branch.

Comment: And when you do this and realize later you used the wrong sha, reflog is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this on a branch (move the head of a branch to an earlier commit on that branch)? This failed: `git push origin/<remote_branch> <sha>:HEAD`

Comment: I tried this in many combinations, and non of them works. Typical error is `Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote`.

Comment: If you're explicitly trying to go backwards you may need to `--force` it.